# How to structure json object for javascript project

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a data structure for my project. It uses json. I am trying to make it easy to search or EDIT the json object. Which structure would be standard. Is there a right or wrong why for would it be okay for me to use either

object with id 2 has parent which is id 1

```
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'First',
        UUID: 123,
        action : null,
        isFolder: true,
        parent: null,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Second',
        UUID: 123,
        action : null,
        isFolder: false,
        parent: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Third',
        UUID: 123,
        action : null,
        isFolder: false
        parent: null,
    },
]
```

structure 2

```
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'First',
        UUID: 123,
        action : null,
        isFolder: true,
        children: [      
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Second',
                UUID: 123,
                action : null,
                isFolder: false,
                children: [],
            },
                ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Third',
        UUID: 123,
        action : null,
        isFolder: false
        children: [],
    },
]
```

Comment: there's not such thing as a JSON object. JSON is always a string. what you have here are plain objects.

Comment: Which one makes more sense to you? I favor the hierarchical children approach myself. - it preserves the relationship visually and architecturally.

Comment: I suggest not to do the 2nd one. 1st its easier to do the searchs, because all nodes are on the same level.

Comment: there is no such thing as "standard" and either format can be mechanically converted to the other. the data is hierarchical or tree-like and structure 2 has a representation to match this, however structure 1 has a linear representation that diverges. both representations have differing advantages and disadvantages when performing operations on each structure. you should also consider structure 3, structure ..., structure N, as each will enable unique benefits. it's impossible for me or anyone else to advise you without know _how_ the structure us going to be used in your particular program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1.  Why?  It's the simplest structure, it will be easy to edit individual nodes, to search, to be read by a human (imagine a model where your children have children have children and it gets hard to look at).  Also, you should consider what has to happen if you want to change a parent?  What if in the future you need to support multiple parents?

At the end of the day you could probably make arguments for either, so you need to choose what you think fits your application, use case, etc.  Do you have any idea of what future enhancements might look like?  Consider those.